# Выровнять блоки

Tags: css, bootstrap

Использую bootstrap 3 и стандартные карточки (эскизы). [Фиддл тут](https://jsfiddle.net/n72tuts8/)

```
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Название товара <small>Доп название</small></h3>
        <p>Лейблы</p>
        <p>Описание товара</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Разделяю страницу на две части - левая для фильтров (сайтбар), а правая для вывода карточек с товарами. Карточки с товарами вывожу по 2 в ряд. Однако если у какой-нибудь из карточек слишком большое содержимое (текстовое описание товара в данном случае), то все карточки ниже едут и отображаются очень криво (смотри скриншот).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже структура HTML с карточками. Использую стандартную сетку bootstrap на 12 столбцов. Как быть? Что можно сделать (помимо того, чтобы на сервере резать текст до определённом длины), чтобы блоки выводились без таких огромных провалов?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка на fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/n72tuts8/

Comment: Добейтесь, чтобы колонки были одинаковой высоты. Для сетки построенной на float-ах это нормальное решение.

Comment: @Александр JSом что ли при любом изменении подтягивать высоту?

Comment: ни в коем случае.

Comment: лучше зафиксируйте высоту каждого элемента внутри карточки и лишний контент обрезайте overflow:hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил с помощью js. Функция находит самый высокий блок и подгоняет остальные под его размер. Вызывать функцию при открытии страницы и при изменении размера экрана.

```
   function rabbit_resizer() {
       let max=0;
       let ob=jQuery('.rabbit').find('.thumbnail');

       ob.each(function () {
           $(this).css('height', '100%');
           if ($(this).height() > max) {
               max=$(this).height();
           }
       });

       ob.each(function () {
           $(this).css('height', max+'px');
       });
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно обратиться к flex, немного доработав у себя сетку.

```
.row-flex, .row-flex > div[class*='col-'] {  
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex:1 1 auto;
}

.row-flex-wrap {
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
    flex:0;
}

.row-flex > div[class*='col-'] {
     margin:-.2px; /* hack adjust for wrapping */
}
```

1) https://jsfiddle.net/timych/uo3ktyqj/1/

2) https://note.dimexio.ru/?p=1307

Ещё можно поиграться с display: inline-block. Тогда сетка не будет ломаться как при float, но визуально всё равно не очень.

Comment: немного позже попробую. Хоть ты на 4 bootstrap переходи. Они там вроде на flex перешли

Answer (score 1):

Можно скриптом выравнивать. Только тогда надо добавить для данного блока

```
.thumbnail {
  height: 100%
}
```

Пример 
[здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/Kniha/w8j7men8/).